# Insert native query in spring

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, oracle11g, hibernate-native-query

I am trying to run an insert native query similar to the following

```
INSERT INTO t3(t1,t2)
SELECT t1.c1,sum(t1.c2) table1 t1 WHERE t1.c3 = 'something'
GROUP BY t1;
```

I am calling it using a repository and the system actually runs the query without any error. However, no value is being inserted. The query works when I try to run using the database interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work. My mistake was not using `@Modifying` annotation on top of the function. I was simple using @Transactional only. If you require more then one table to be impacted simultaneously then use the annotation as well. It got the job done for me. exapme snippet below

```
  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  @Query(value = Query.YOUR_QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
  void insert(@Param("param") var param1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the query in your database, alternatively you dont need group by in insert scripts

Comment: I require them to run as a corn job for reports

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: oracle 11g. These Infos are mentioned

Comment: does your query run in your db interface?

Comment: yes. It also even fires in console